# Windows 10 Unexpectedly Shutting Down

Tags: windows-10, crash

I have a desktop, it's about five years old. Custom built by yours truly.

It's been working great up until about two weeks ago. I leave it on 24/7, so I was surprised one day when I came home and it was powered off. I powered it back on, but after about 10 minutes it just turned itself off again.

This has since happened about 10 times since then. When it shuts off, it's as if the power cord was pulled from the wall. No BSOD, no warnings, errors... nothing. I know it's not thermal related because I've used RealTemp to log the temps and it never goes about 40C.

The only thing I see in the Event Viewer under Windows Logs > System is this:

```
The system has rebooted without cleanly shutting down first. This error could be
caused if the system stopped responding, crashed, or lost power unexpectedly.
```

When it happens I'm just browsing the internet or writing code. It actually even happened while I was typing this question (thank god for Chrome's *restore tabs* feature). Nothing CPU/GPU intensive. I hear the fans spinning but very quietly (at their normal idle speed when there's no load). So I really don't think it's a thermal issue.

I've done the built-in Windows 10 memory test (where it reboots and does the test). It came back with no errors. I also downloaded Samsung Magician (for my SSD) and did a performance test and looked at the S.M.A.R.T. info. Everything looks fine in there.

So I guess my real question is: is there any way to diagnose this without swapping each component out of my PC one at a time? Are there any log files I can look for? What should my next steps be?

**Update**: Even after leaving the computer in the BIOS for 30 minutes it turns off. I would also like to add that it is happening after being on for 30 minutes exactly. Not 29, not 31, not 30:05; 30 minutes exactly.

My motherboard is an ASUS Sabertooth Z77. Has anyone else heard of this?

Comment: This sounds like a hardware issue to me, but you could always try running a Linux live CD (to see if it crashes) to completely rule out a software/driver problem.

Comment: Can you turn it on again immediately? Your PSU could be malfunctioning, triggering one of its protection circuits.

Comment: Could be the PSU failing when the hardware starts doing activities that require more power, happened something similar to me when using a crappy PSU.

Comment: @DanielB Yes I can turn it back on again immediately. In fact, the lights on my GPU don't even turn off when the system goes down (since it's powered by the PSU directly).

Comment: But I don't think it's the PSU... this is happening when I'm just sitting in the BIOS as well. Not a very power-demanding activity...

Comment: So I RMA'd the motherboard (after 5+ years; ASUS ♥). Everything working now.